# Opening modal on select event fullcalendar v4

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, react-modal

I am using the fullcalendar v4 and at the moment I'm trying to open a modal on select event. After selecting a period of time from my calendar, I'm calling a function that changes the state for 'isOpen' prop of the modal, but the modal doesnt'show. Also my calendar is getting an error after calling that function.  I'm getting an error which says that my calendar is not defined. I'm mentioning that I'm using react [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4tlF.png)

Comment: Could you add some codes? Which libraries are you using? How are you calling the functions?

Comment: Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770196/fullcalendar-modal-not-displayed

Comment: This thread opens modal on event click, but you may try same type of logic on select. I think you might need to make calendar object is global variable so that it will be accessible in other functions where it is not defined, or pass calendar object to function using parameter.

Comment: @emert117 this would summarize what I've done till now: https://imgur.com/a/JVPTTVb here I have my Appointment component which is rendering the Fullcalendar and at the bottom is the AddAppointment component. here it is https://imgur.com/a/QvbdMyT . As I mentioned I want it to be shown when the the select event is triggered from the Fullcalendar. Also, the info from handleSelect is logged, but I'm getting many errors after that https://imgur.com/a/3bVOhl0 .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was that I was using the version 4.4.0 for daygrid, interaction & timegrid. If you want to open a modal using the select function from fullcalendar, I recommend you to use version 4.2.0.

Comment: Do you think there is a bug in 4.4 then? If so please read https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs